# private counter static variable getting incremented when instantiated from derived class

Tags: php, oop

How is the $count static attribute getting incremented when its declared as private,when i instantiate the derived class(counter2),it still is getting incremented?I dont know how its getting incremented when i instantiate a derived class here

```
class counter{ 

/*** our count variable ***/
private static $count = 0;

/*Constructor*/
function __construct() {
  self::$count++;
  } 

/*get the current count
* @access public
* @return int*/
public static function getCount() { 
   return self::$count; 
   } 
  } /*** end of class ***/
//extend the counter class
class counter2 extends counter{
}
/*** create a new instance ***/
$count = new counter(); 
/*** get the count ***/
echo counter::getCount() . '<br />';
/*** create another instance ***/
$next = new counter(); 
/*** echo the new count ***/
echo counter::getCount().'<br />'; 
/*** and a third instance ***/
$third = new counter;
echo counter::getCount().'<br />';
$count2=new counter2();
echo counter2::getCount();
```

output:
    1
    2
    3
    4

Answer (score 0):

Your class counter2 has an implicit constructor which calls the constructor of its superclass, which has access to the private variable and increments it when it is called.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple and you can also find it in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

And a quote from there:

> **Note:** Parent constructors are not called implicitly **if the child class defines a constructor**

So if you don't want it to be incremented, you can simply declare a empty constructor like this:

```
class counter2 extends counter{
    public function __construct() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a default constructor of counter class..and there u want increment static counter. As you know static variable retain there memory(value).That's why its incrementing.Other wise you could simply use private dont make it static.

```
private or protected count = 0;
```

or if else please tell me what output you want..

Thanks